# Define/declare new custom types with fields in plugin?

Tags: custom-post-types, pods-framework

I want to develop a plugin using Pods but I want to create all the necessary custom types, fields, etc… on activation of my plugin. Is it possible?

what are the good practices/approach? my plugin would depend on pods framework but everything done in code without the user having to create the custom types and fields via admin ui manually.

Comment: We're working on code-based registration for Pods, the code is there but we're optimizing things in the DB for ID-less Pods and Fields in relationships which is where things can get sticky. All of the changes are coming in Pods 3.0

Comment: ok thx. when is 3.0 going to be released?

Comment: I really don't have an answer on that yet, we have a major merge to do with Pods 2.4 >> Pods 3.0 and performance optimizations to do that are coming from the new WP Metadata API / UI project. Could be 1-2 months out right now, but I'll work my hardest to get it out as soon as it can be out.